# How to iteratively perform expand.grid in R

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration, distribution, probability

I am writing a piece of R code and got stuck.

**Background** (which is not necessary for solving the problem): I am calculating the joint probability by multiplying independent marginal distributions. The marginal probability vectors are generated by the ProbGenerationProcess() iteratively. At each iteration it will output a vector, eg.

```
Iteration 1:
Color =
   Blue  Green
   0.2    0.8   

Iteration 2:
Material =
   Cotton  Silk
    0.7     0.3

Iteration 3:
Country =
   China     USA
    0.6      0.4

......
```

**Desired result:** I want the resulted joint probability to be the product of every single element in each marginal vector. The format should look like this.

```
Color   Material  Country   Prob
Blue    Cotton     China    0.084  (= 0.2*0.7*0.6)
Blue    Cotton     USA      0.056  (= 0.2*0.7*0.4)
Blue    Silk       China    0.036  (= 0.2*0.3*0.6)
Blue    Silk       USA      ..
Green   Cotton     China    ..
Green   Cotton     USA      ..
...     ...        ...      ...
```

**My Implementation:** Here's my code:

```
joint.names = NULL  # data.from store the marginal value names
joint.probs = NULL  # store probabilities.

for (i in iterations) {
    marginal = ProbGenerationProcess(VarUniqueToIteration) # output is numeric with names

    if ( is.null(joint.names) ) {
        # initialize the dataframes
        joint.names = names(marginal)
        joint.probs = marginal
    } else {
        # (my hope:) iteratively populate the joint.names and joint.probs

        joint.names = expand.grid(joint.names, names(marginal))

        expanded.prob = expand.grid(joint.probs, marginal)
        joint.probs = expanded.prob$Var1 * expanded.prob$Var2 # Row-by-row multiplication.
    }
}
```

**Output:** Joint.probs turnout out to be always correct, However, joint.names doesn't quite work the way I wanted. After the first two iterations everything works well. I got:

```
joint.names = 
    Var1  Var2
1   Blue  Cotton
2   Green Cotton
3   Blue  Silk
4   Green Silk 
    ...   ...
```

Start from the third iteration it become problematic:

```
joint.names =
    Var1.Var1  Var1.Var2  Var1.Var1.1  Var1.Var2.1  Var2
1   Blue       Cotton     Blue         Cotton       China 
2   Green      Cotton     Green        Cotton       China
3   Blue       Silk       Blue         Silk         USA
4   Green      Silk       Green        Silk         USA
```

I guess my first question is: is this the most efficient way to get the result I wanted? If so, is expand.grid() the function I should be using, and how should I initialize it correctly?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge is your friend.

```
color <- data.frame(color=c("blue","green"),prob=c(0.2,0.8))
material <- data.frame(material=c("cotton","silk"),prob=c(0.7,0.3))
country <- data.frame(country=c("china","usa"),prob=c(0.6,0.4))

dat <- merge(merge(color[1],material[1]),country[1]) # get names first

# same as: expand.grid(c("china","usa"),c("cotton","silk"),c("blue","green"))

dat <- merge(dat, color, by="color")
dat <- merge(dat, material, by="material")
dat <- merge(dat, country, by="country")

dat$joint <- dat$prob.x * dat$prob.y * dat$prob # joint calc

dat <- dat[-grep("^prob",colnames(dat))] # cleanup extra probs
```

Result:

```
  country material color joint
1   china   cotton  blue 0.084
2   china   cotton green 0.336
3   china     silk  blue 0.036
4   china     silk green 0.144
5     usa   cotton  blue 0.056
6     usa   cotton green 0.224
7     usa     silk  blue 0.024
8     usa     silk green 0.096
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this for simlicity (although if performance is an issue, maybe better with merge)

```
PROBS<-data.frame(Item=rep(c("Color","Material","Country"),each=2),
           Value=c("Blue","Green","Cotton","Silk","China","USA"),
           Prob=c(0.2,0.8,0.7,0.3,0.6,0.4))

rownames(PROBS)<-PROBS$Value

GRID<-expand.grid(by(PROBS,PROBS$Item,function(x)x["Value"]))

GRID$probs<-apply(GRID,1,function(x)prod(PROBS[c(x),"Prob"]))

GRID
#  Color Country Material probs
#1  Blue   China   Cotton 0.084
#2 Green   China   Cotton 0.336
#3  Blue     USA   Cotton 0.056
#4 Green     USA   Cotton 0.224
#5  Blue   China     Silk 0.036
#6 Green   China     Silk 0.144
#7  Blue     USA     Silk 0.024
#8 Green     USA     Silk 0.096
```

Comment: rownames(PROBS)<-PROBS$Value is really smart! The merge solution seems more intuitive but thanks for showing me how to use expand.grid properly here.